# Google api response time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

I am using google RESTApis (geocoder api and google places detail api)

Each time I hit a api the response time varies i.e if for first hit it is giving me a response time of 2 second,for the second hit it is taking upto 6 to 8 second.

Please help me out with this how can I reduce the response time?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure its the api's response time that is changing and not some processing in your code, do you get the same difference when you try it postman, and if yes then it could be a number of things, network latency issues or depends on how the API works itself

Comment: yes the api response time is changing because no code is processing in between two api hits.

Comment: do you get similar time differences when you try with https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Subash I haven't tried it with postman let me try it and get back to you.

Comment: Hi @Subash I have checked and the response time is different in postman as well.Is it possible that it is due to different parameters?

Comment: could be, but don't you mean you get the time difference with the exact same request

Comment: parameters are same but the values are different (i.e for 1st hit name='abc' for 2nd name='xyz')

Comment: that shouldn't be an issue, unless change in value requires the api to do different things, it could be mostly latency issues, is it possible to share the request, maybe I can hit it and see if I get similar differences

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164304/discussion-between-kajal-ojha-and-subash).